# How to remove a line containing text from a string in swift

Tags: swift, string, xcode, integer, substring

I need to remove lines from a string that contain certain text. For instance:

"this is 1 line

this is the second

this is line number 3 that needs to be removed

this is a line that doesn't"

I need to remove any line that has the word "removed" in it so that the new string would be:

"this is 1 line

this is the second

this is a line that doesn't"

and ideally it would return any integer that was contained in that line.  So I would now have the string without the removed line, as well as the integer 3 in another variable.

The lines that will need to be removed do not necessarily conform to any structure, they will only have the keyword and a possible integer.

I have tried using

```
myString.replacingOccurrences(of: "removed", with "")
```

but that will only remove that word and not the entire line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and let me know if any additional information is needed.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `filter` function for that:

```
let lines = ["this is 1 line", "this is the second", "this is line number 3 that needs to be removed", "this is a line that doesn't"]

let filteredLines = lines.filter { $0.contains("removed") == false }
```

Result:

`["this is 1 line", "this is the second", "this is a line that doesn't"]`

EDIT:

To also get the number 3 out, try this:

```
let lines = ["this is 1 line", "this is the second", "this is line number 3 that needs to be removed", "this is a line that doesn't"]

var result:  [String] = []
var number: String = ""

lines.forEach {
    if $0.contains("removed") {
        if let range = $0.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits) {
            number = String($0[range])
        }
    }
    else {
        result.append($0)
    }
}

print(number)
print(result)
```

Result:

`3`

`["this is 1 line", "this is the second", "this is a line that doesn't"]`

Comment: Appreciate the help! I needed to change let number = String($0[range]).intValue to let number = String($0[range]) and it worked perfectly!

Comment: I removed the `intValue`, and pulled out the `number` variable from the loop.